# Unable to switch between options

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple application which could show me basic information about my network interface card. The application is working but when I am switching the radio buttons it always shows the same output. How can I fix this?
I am not sure how it would work on a device which does not have a wifi or ethernet driver installed but that's not the thing which I am asking. The nicInfo returns a tupple and based on the radio buttons it will return MAC and IP address of ehternet or Wi-FI and when it is set to have the initial value zero it will display the info of ethernet and when I try to switch it to wifi it still shows the info of the ethernet.

```
from Tkinter import *
from netifaces import ifaddresses, interfaces
from re import match

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Verdana 10 bold')
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.show()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.whichOne = IntVar()
        self.output = StringVar()
        self.whichOne.set(0)
        Radiobutton(self, text = 'Ethernet', padx = 10, pady = 10, variable = self.whichOne, value =0).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text = 'Wi-Fi', padx = 10, pady = 10, variable = self.whichOne, value =1).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        Button(self, text='QUIT', fg='red', command=self.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)

    def show(self):
        self.hexInt = interfaces()
        if True:
            self.nic = self.nicInfo(self.whichOne.get())
            selection = 'The MAC address of your device is %s\n' % (self.nic[0]) + '\nThe IP address of your device is %s\n' % (self.nic[1])
            Label(text=selection).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def nicInfo(self, index):
        self.mac = 'unknown'
        for mainKey in ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index]): # a DICT which contains a LIST, in which is a DICT
            for subKey in ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0]: #this zero has to be here
                if match(r'([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})', ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey]):
                    self.mac = ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey].upper()
                elif match(r'((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])', ifaddresses(self.hexInt[0])[mainKey][0][subKey]) and subKey == 'addr':
                    self.ip = ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey]
        return self.mac, self.ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('MAC')
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Radiobuttons use command= which calls a function which determines the button that is active.  See the example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm

Comment: @CurlyJoe: the command isn't for determining which is active -- you can do that just as easily without the command. The command is for getting notified when the current one changes.

Comment: Have you tried to figure out why it's returning the same information? For example, is the data exactly what you think it is? Have you verified that the regexes return the proper result for each case? How do you know if it's the data or the logic? Do a little debugging and then update your question.

Comment: Yes I've tried to find out why it is not working. The whole nicInfo function is working properly on my device. I am not sure how it would work on a device which does not have a wifi or ethernet driver installed but that's not the thing which I am asking. The nicInfo returns a tupple and based on the radio buttons it will return MAC and IP address of ehternet or Wi-FI and when it is set to have the initial value zero ("self.whichOne.set(0)") it will display the info of ethernet and when I try to switch it to wifi it still shows the info of the ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your radiobuttons doesn't have any function if you click them. So your `show()` method will be only called once, thats why your text doesn't change. Use the `command` option of your Radiobuttons to bind a method to them. This results in this code:

```
class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.option_add('*Font', 'Verdana 10 bold')
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.show()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.whichOne = IntVar()
        self.output = StringVar()
        self.whichOne.set(0)
        Radiobutton(self, text = 'Ethernet', padx = 10, pady = 10, variable = self.whichOne, value =0, command=self.show).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Radiobutton(self, text = 'Wi-Fi', padx = 10, pady = 10, variable = self.whichOne, value =1, command=self.show).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        Button(self, text='QUIT', fg='red', command=self.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, rowspan=2, columnspan=2)

    def show(self):
        self.hexInt = interfaces()
        if True:
            self.nic = self.nicInfo(self.whichOne.get())
            selection = 'The MAC address of your device is %s\n' % (self.nic[0]) + '\nThe IP address of your device is %s\n' % (self.nic[1])
            Label(text=selection).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

    def nicInfo(self, index):
        self.mac = 'unknown'
        for mainKey in ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index]): # a DICT which contains a LIST, in which is a DICT
            for subKey in ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0]: #this zero has to be here
                if match(r'([0-9a-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9a-f]{2})', ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey]):
                    self.mac = ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey].upper()
                elif match(r'((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9]\.){3}((2[0-5]|1[0-9]|[0-9])?[0-9])',
                           ifaddresses(self.hexInt[0])[mainKey][0][subKey]) and\
                           subKey == 'addr':
                    self.ip = ifaddresses(self.hexInt[index])[mainKey][0][subKey]
        return self.mac, self.ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('MAC')
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Nevertheless i was getting a Exception: `KeyError: 'broadcast'` from `nicInfo()` after i switched to `WiFi`, even thouh i have wifi